# Content Management System for RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

I have a created a website and wanted to integrate it with a CMS such that start page, blog, support requests etc will be managed by a CMS and it will redirect it to the main website through say login button.

Technology stack used is RoR and was wondering if there is a CMS which manages start page, blog, support requests and redirects to the main website through a link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you looking for a CMS in Rails: http://www.exist.com/blog/five-popular-ruby-rails-based-cms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try one of the best CMS's I have used: [Refinary CMS](http://refinerycms.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are plenty of options. I would encourage you to check out the [content management systems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/content_management_systems) category on the Ruby Toolbox for options. Most can be used as a component of a larger app.